# How can I write a simple combination of superscripts and a word in ggplot2 labels?

Tags: r, ggplot2, labeling

I would like to write on the x and y axes of the ggplot the following expression: LE flux [W m-1]. My solution is:

```
xlab(expression("LE flux [W m""~"^{-2}"~]")).
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work.
Appreciate any help!

Comment: `bquote('LE flux [W'~ m^-2 ~']')` or `expression`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do `labs(x = expression('blah'))`

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg))+
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = expression('LE flux [W'~ m^-2 ~']'), y = expression('LE flux [W'~ m^-2 ~']'))
```

[image]